# In CBOW model, do we need to take Average at Hidden layer?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

I search and read some articles about CBOW. But seem to have difference between these articles.

As I understand:

- Input is a batch vector. And we will feed it to Hidden layer. So that we will get another **batch vector H** at Hidden layer.
- In an [article (part 2.2.1)](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/06/word-embeddings-count-word2veec/), they say that we will not use any Activation Function at Hidden layer, but we will **take average on *batch vector H*** to get a single vector (not a batch anymore). Then we will feed this average vector to Output layer and apply Softmax on it.

[image]

- However, in this [Coursera's video](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/probabilistic-models-in-nlp/training-a-cbow-model-forward-propagation-Vphwi), they *don't* take average on batch vector H. They just feed this batch vector H to Output layer and apply Softmax on batch Output vector. And then calculate Cost function on it.
- And, in [Coursera's video](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/probabilistic-models-in-nlp/training-a-cbow-model-forward-propagation-Vphwi), they say that we can use RelU as Activation function at Hidden layer. Is this a new method? Because I read many articles, but they always say that there is no Activation function at Hidden layer.

Can you please help me to answer it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In actual implementations – whose source code you can review – the set of context-word vectors are averaged together *before* being fed as the "input" to the neural-network.

Then, any back-propagated adjustments to the input are also applied to all the vectors contributing to that average.

(For example, in the original `word2vec.c` released with Google's original word2vec paper, you can see the tallying of vectors into `neu1`, then averaging via division by the context-window count `cw`, at:

https://github.com/tmikolov/word2vec/blob/master/word2vec.c#L444-L448
)

Comment: Thank you so so much. I feel a lot clearer. So I can think that in Coursera's video, they seem to have used some new approach?

Comment: I haven't reviewed the Coursera video, but your reference to (plain) softmax makes me think they're providing a high-level, approximate, theoretical view of what motivated the word2vec algorithm. Actual implementations tend to offer either hierarchical-softmax or negative-sampling instead of literal plain softmax as their method for predicting/backpropagating - for efficiency. (Plain softmax would work, but those alternate 'sparse' training methods are far more efficient in practice.) Again, I'd focus on source code if you want to know *exactly* what real code is doing.